# LEFT OUTER JOIN with Condition in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want the following query in EF (LINQ or Lamda).

```
SELECT S.Id, 
       S.Name, 
       S.Description, 
       S.Active, 
       R.Id AS RoleFunctionId, 
       R.SystemRoleId, 
       ISNULL(R.AllowView, 0) AS AllowView, 
       ISNULL(R.AllowAdd, 0) AS AllowAdd, 
       ISNULL(R.AllowEdit, 0) AS AllowEdit, 
       ISNULL(R.AllowDelete, 0) AS AllowDelete 
FROM SystemRoleFunction AS S 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RoleFunction AS R 
    ON S.Id = R.SystemRoleFunctionId 
   AND R.SystemRoleId = 21 
ORDER BY S.Id
```

But I'm confused since the query comes with **LEFT OUTER JOIN** and a **AND** expression. That is the tricky part here. When I put the where condition or the AND clause at the end, I'm not getting the expected result when I do it in EF.

I want to see all records from Table S even though Table R doesn't have any respected records.

When I tried the following way, I'm getting **"The cast to value type 'System.Guid' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."** error. Because some records return null from Table R.

```
var b = await (from S in _db.SystemRoleFunctions
                        join z in _db.RoleFunctions on S.Id equals z.SystemRoleFunctionId into fg
                        from R in fg.Where(x => x.SystemRoleId == 21).DefaultIfEmpty()
                               select new
                               {
                                   S.Name,
                                   S.Description,
                                   S.Active,
                                   S.Tstamp,
                                   R.Id,
                                   R.SystemRoleId,
                                   R.SystemRoleFunctionId,
                                   AllowView = R == null ? false : R.AllowView,
                                   AllowAdd = R == null ? false : R.AllowAdd,
                                   AllowEdit = R == null ? false : R.AllowEdit,
                                   AllowDelete = R == null ? false : R.AllowDelete,
                               }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I don't see a `where` clause in your query

Comment: Sorry. What I meant is AND clause. 

LEFT OUTER JOIN RoleFunction AS R 
    ON S.Id = R.SystemRoleFunctionId 
   **AND** R.SystemRoleId = 21

I edited the post

Comment: I don't know EF but should not the `SystemRoleId == 21` be in the join in stead of in a where at the end ?

Comment: @GuidoG
In that case, I'm getting **'The cast to value type 'System.Guid' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'** error.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue in the following way. Thanks to @GuidoG for pointing me out.

```
                var a = await (from S in _db.SystemRoleFunctions
                           join z in _db.RoleFunctions.Where(x => x.SystemRoleId == 21) on S.Id equals z.SystemRoleFunctionId into jointable
                           from R in jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new
                           {
                               S.Name,
                               S.Description,
                               S.Active,
                               S.Tstamp,
                               SystemRoleId = R == null ? 21: R.SystemRoleId,
                               RoleFunctionId = R == null ? Guid.NewGuid() : R.Id,
                               SystemRoleFunctionId = R == null ? S.Id : R.SystemRoleFunctionId,
                               AllowView = R == null ? false : R.AllowView,
                               AllowAdd = R == null ? false : R.AllowAdd,
                               AllowEdit = R == null ? false : R.AllowEdit,
                               AllowDelete = R == null ? false : R.AllowDelete,
                           }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: yes this is what I mean, get the restriction on 21 in the joined table in stead of a where at the end

Answer (score 1):

This is simplified version and documentation: [Collection selector references outer in a where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause)

```cs
var a = await (
    from S in _db.SystemRoleFunctions
    from R in _db.RoleFunctions
        .Where(x => x.SystemRoleId == 21 && S.Id == x.SystemRoleFunctionId)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        S.Name,
        S.Description,
        S.Active,
        S.Tstamp,
        SystemRoleId = R == null ? 21: R.SystemRoleId,
        RoleFunctionId = R == null ? Guid.NewGuid() : R.Id,
        SystemRoleFunctionId = R == null ? S.Id : R.SystemRoleFunctionId,
        AllowView = R == null ? false : R.AllowView,
        AllowAdd = R == null ? false : R.AllowAdd,
        AllowEdit = R == null ? false : R.AllowEdit,
        AllowDelete = R == null ? false : R.AllowDelete,
    }
    ).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, it is returning the same result. Upvoted.